# Getting row number from my results

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, row-number

My brain is not working tonight!

### Data

```
Id int, Name varchar, Tag varchar, MilesAway decimal(9,6)
```

I'm trying to add the `row_number` to my result set, but I want to ignore the duplicate rows that are caused by the tag. Here's expected output:

- 1 Blah Red 6.3 -> desired output: 1
- 1 Blah Stripe 6.3 -> desired output: 1
- 19 SomethingElse Red 12.1 -> desired output: 2
- 19 SomethingElse Straight 12.1 -> desired output: 2
- 5 Hello Red 15.9 -> desired output: 3
- 42 Bye Red 55.0 -> desired output: 4

So, I should have result numbers 1, 2, 3, 4. Here's how I'm writing my query:

```
select  Id,
        Name,
        Tag,
        MilesAway,
        row_number() over (order by MilesAway)
from    table t
group by Id,
        Name,
        Tag,
        MilesAway
```

I've also tried adding `partition by` to all columns except tag. I know this, I've written hundreds of these, why am I stumped (other than it being midnight!)?

Edit: I want to ignore the fact that there are 2 records in spot number 1, and still want the next one to be 2, NOT 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `dense_rank`:

```
select Id,
    name,
    Tag,
    MilesAway,
    dense_rank() over (
        order by MilesAway
        )
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
select Id, name,Tag, MilesAway, dense_rank() over ( order by MilesAway)
from table t
group by Id, Name,Tag, MilesAway
```

Answer (score -1):

select Id,name,Tag,MilesAway,
    dense_rank() over (
        order by MilesAway
        )from table ;